# AWS EMR cluster with cloudformation: how to enable debugging

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-emr

When creating an EMR cluster via the UI, I can click 'enable debugging'.

Via the cli, I can add the parameter `--enable-debugging`.

How can I do it via cloudformation? I did give a `LogUri`, where I do see the logs, but the EMR web UI carries on telling me 'Debugging not configured' when running Spark jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just is added as the first step in the steps...so the equivalent of the below in CloudFormation config.

```
"Steps": [{
  "Name": "Setup Hadoop Debugging",
  "ActionOnFailure": "TERMINATE_CLUSTER",
  "HadoopJarStep": {
    "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
    "Args": ["state-pusher-script"]
  }
}]
```

Comment: for more context on GH, see here: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1419

Comment: an update here: it seems that if one is using `run_job_flow` to provision/use transient EMR clusters, this is possibly not an option. that command "creates" the cluster but after enough research it seems that to create/enable debugging too, one  must do so via the SDK or CLI one time. the so-called "state-pusher-script" can't be an update type of thing, it has to be the single command of creating the cluster with all its config.

Comment: bottom line: I'd really think it'd be helpful to have some form of the pusher script referenced above

Comment: I haven’t tried this out but even RunJobFlow has steps that you can add. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_RunJobFlow.html

Comment: last update on this: aws failures to clearly document this but in case you're wondering like I've been, the args for the so-called "state-pusher-script" is actually a valid, existing, and presumably inaccessible file. just run it all as-is above.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is *almost* correct.

I received an error while deploying: `CloudFormation currently only supports long-running clusters, set ActionOnFailure to CANCEL_AND_WAIT or CONTINUE`.

So, the following code worked for me (also, YAML version for those, who would like to copypaste that format):

```yaml
Steps:
  - Name: SetupHadoopDebugging
    ActionOnFailure: CONTINUE
    HadoopJarStep:
      Jar: command-runner.jar
      Args:
        - 'state-pusher-script'
```